# how to load image from localhost server into imageview android

Tags: android, kotlin

im having probleme loading images from the local host into imageView in my android app
i tried using picasso and glid but none of them work .
the images are stored in xampp on my pc , im connecting my phisical device to my pc and using usb tethering to acces the localhost . the probleme is not in the connection between the phone and the device because iam able to insert into the database on the server and olso i can acces the localhost on my divice using the ipv4 address .
piccasso code  `val picasso = Picasso.get() picasso.load("http://192.168.107.247/phpFiles/mytaxi/img/mimg.jpg") .into(img)`
glid code `Glide.with(this).load("http://192.168.107.247/phpFiles/mytaxi/img/ming.jpg").into(img)`

also this i tryed this link that im using in the code above
and its getting the image correctly as you can see in the image below
[image]
so if any one know the solution please help

Answer (score 0):

With Picasso you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61890208/18015674).

I have converted this code in kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 loadLogo("https://192.168.1.112/media/logo.9d457cd5.png")
}

private fun getUnsafeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return try {
        val trustAllCerts: Array<TrustManager> = arrayOf<TrustManager>(
            object : X509TrustManager {
                @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                override fun checkClientTrusted(
                    chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?,
                    authType: String?
                ) {
                }

                @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                override fun checkServerTrusted(
                    chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?,
                    authType: String?
                ) {
                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                    return arrayOf()
                }

            }
        )

        val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())

        val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
        builder.hostnameVerifier { _,_ -> true }
        builder.build()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}

fun loadLogo(url: String?) {
    if (url != null && url.isNotEmpty()) {
        val picassoClient = getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
        val picasso = Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(picassoClient)).build()
        picasso.isLoggingEnabled = true
        picasso.load(url).into(findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView))
    }
}
```

Obviously it will be used as long as you use an uncertified local server.

Comment: unfortunately did'ngt work for me